# With the mongoDB C# driver, how do I issue a runCommand?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The mongoDB API documentation seems to be lacking in this area.  I am trying to use the aggregate function to get a count of popular tags in a certain collection.  Here is the command I wish to execute:

```
db.runCommand(
       { aggregate : "articles", 
         pipeline : [ { $unwind : "$Tags" }, 
                      { $group : { _id : "$Tags", count : { $sum : 1 } }
                      } ]});
```

When I execute this using the shell, I get the following:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "_id": "2012",
        "count": 3
    }, {
        "_id": "seattle",
        "count": 5
    }],
    "ok": 1
}
```

I'm using c# 4.0, so I guess I would prefer to get this back as a dynamic object, but I'll take whatever I can get...

FWIW, I am using mongoDB for Windows, 32 bit, v2.1.1 (Nightly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the corresponding C# Driver Doc page: [RunCommand()](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.3.1/html/4fe0d8b2-161e-ff83-355d-7517b251d81a.htm). So basically you call `Database.RunCommand("MyCommand")`. This ticket in JIRA may come handy for an example of more complex commands requiring (multiple) properties: [CSHARP-478](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-478)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I know I can use the RunCommand with a pre-built command, like RunCommand("repairDatabase").  But I want to run the JSON query listed above.  Can I simply do RunCommand("{ aggregate: .... }")?

Comment: Therefore the [IMongoCommand](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.3.1/html/70d9353e-6218-8425-ffe4-71eb39f24cbd.htm) overloaded function is there. Further look at this [ticket CSHARP-383](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-383) to see an example.

Comment: Awesome.  The example in the ticket was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB CSharp Drivers 2.0.0+:
I use below syntax to run such commands:

```
var command = new CommandDocument
{
    {"aggregate", "TestCollection"},
    {
        "pipeline", new BsonArray
        {
            new BsonDocument {{"$unwind", "$Tags"}},
            new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "$group", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {"_id", "$Tags"},
                        {"count", new BsonDocument {{"$sum", 1}}}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var result = db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command)["result"]
    .AsBsonArray.ToList();
```