# Execute Raw Mongodb Query with c# driver v2

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following code :

```
MongoClient m = new MongoClient();
        var db = m.GetDatabase("PopupRentals");



        string cmdDoc = (@"
                            db.Rentals.find({polygons:
                                             {$geoIntersects:
                                                 {$geometry:{ 'type' : 'Point',
                                                      'coordinates' : [ 17.3734, 78.4738 ]
                                }
                            }
                                              }
                                         });");

        var cmd = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>(cmdDoc);

        var res = db.RunCommand(cmd);

        var result = db.GetCollection<RentalProperty>("Rentals");
```

I am using the standard mongodb v2 driver.

Once i execute the query i get the following error at about the

```
db.RunCommand(cmd);

System.FormatException: 'JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'db'.'
```

I have not the slightest clue why this is not working. It works great in Robo.

Answer (score 6):

Your `string cmdDoc` is not in proper format for using it the way you want to use it. Based on the [MongoDB docs for the `find` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/#dbcmd.find), your string should look like this:

```
string cmdDoc = @"
                    {
                      find: "Rentals",
                      filter: {
                                polygons: {
                                            $geoIntersects: {
                                                              $geometry: { 
                                                                           'type' : 'Point',
                                                                           'coordinates' : [ 17.3734, 78.4738 ]
                                                                         }
                                                            }
                                          }
                              }
                    }"
```

or without all the extra whitespace for formatting:

```
string cmdDoc = @"{
                    find: "Rentals",
                    filter: { polygons: { $geoIntersects: { $geometry: { 'type' : 'Point', 'coordinates' : [ 17.3734, 78.4738 ] } } } }
                  }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in your Mongo Shell **db** is referring to the Database configured by default in mongo Shell or any corresponding tool which you are using.

In the same shell or tool you can even change that **db** to **database** or something else and can use like **database.collectionName**

where in case while you are passing string as input and specifying **db** as database and expecting results.

Even I aslo tried for some better results.

(i) [With the mongoDB C# driver, how do I issue a runCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909063/with-the-mongodb-c-sharp-driver-how-do-i-issue-a-runcommand)

(ii)

```
 var _server = new MongoClient(new MongoUrl("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
        var db = _server.GetDatabase("DBName");
        var cmdRes =
        @"{
                'aggregate': 'collectionName',
                'allowDiskUse': true,
                'pipeline':[
                    {
                        '$match':{
                            '_id':'5e2b3328d53dc61f2cc6f54c'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                'cursor': { 'batchSize': 25 }
        }";
        var v = db.RunCommand<object>(cmdRes);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v));
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/dotnet/examples/mongodb-remote-access/